How to find the matrix layout of an old EEPC keyboard
The title asks my question; how can I find the matrix layout of an old EEPC keyboard. I found an instructables about making a USB keyboard controller but it uses a Teensy microcontroller, and I think they are a bit too expensive. So I wanted to use a Raspberry Pi Pico. The instructables gives me an Arduino sketch that can decide the matrix. But the code doesn’t wanna compile with a Pico. So how can I either change the code to work with the Pico or find out how the matrix is made, with for example a datasheet?
Btw: sorry for bad english

Please document an "old EEPC keyboard". When i needed to work out the keyboard of an IBM Model 85 Electronic Typewriter so that I could turn it into a printer, I just 'scoped out the timing and details, manually, without any schematics. With data in hand I designed an 8051 board to work between my IBM PC/AT and this typewriter (never intended for computer control) and wrote code. Worked perfectly the first time I powered it up. Never changed a thing after. Worked for many years. Use your own head!! Don't depend on others or their sketches. Just think. Then solve. So narrow it down for us.

the matrix is irrelevant to the code doesn’t wanna compile problem ... if you determine the correct the matrix, then the code will still not compile

You can always look at the matrix wiring if you can open the keybord and see where each wire goes.
Or measure with a multimeter which two pins are shorted when you press some button.
We also don't see why your code does not compile on your platform so we don't know how to change it. Scanning a matrix is just simply setting and reading IO pins so all you need to do is to set IO pins and read them, which every platform supports. You only need to know how to set and read IO pin to scan your matrix.
